# My code that conducts a google search needs improvement

Tags: python, search

This is part of my program where you input a command(variable com) and if the command contains google or search it conducts a google search.
Can someone help fix it so it can also work with searches that contain google(for example: 'google how google makes money').

```
if 'google' in com or 'search' in com:
    search=''
    foo=com.split()        
    for x in foo:
        if x!='google' and x!='search':
            search+='+'+x
    search=search[1:]
    print('googling:'+search)
    time.sleep(1)
    web.open('https://www.google.co.in/search?q='+search+'&oq='+search+'&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61j69i60j69i61.306j0j9&s0ourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing all parts from the search request that are `google` or `search`, no matter where they are located in your `com` variable.

Just split it into `first:rest`, such that you hold the command (only first word of `cmd`) and request (rest words of `cmd`):

```
com = 'google how google makes money'
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={query:s}'
pts = com.split()
cmd, qry = pts[0], ' '.join(pts[1:])
```

Which then is:

```
print(cmd)
>>> 'google'
print(qry)
>>> 'how google makes money'
```

Then, you can perform your query as usual. By the way: you don't need to provide the full url including all tokens that you copied from your browser:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if cmd in ['google', 'search']:
    res = requests.get(url.format(query=qry))
    sup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    res_root = sup.find('div', id='ires')
    for entry in res_root.find_all('h3'):
        print(entry.text)
```

Yields:

```
How Does Google Make Its Money? | Investopedia
The Business of Google (GOOG) | Investopedia
BBC iWonder - How does Google make money?
How does Google earn money? - Quora
How Google Makes Money? - Revenues & Profits
How Does Google Make Money? - Minterest
If Google is free, how does it make so much money? – Channel 4 ...
Four ways Google makes money outside of advertising - TechRepublic
Google - How (precisely) it profits from YouTube - STL Partners ...
How Google's Money-Making Machine, AdWords, Actually Works ...
```